# Работа с Firebird 1.5. Java. Android

Tags: java, база-данных, firebird

Проблема: нужно подключиться к базе данных Firebird 1.5.
Что мне дали:

> IP: 193.110.163.13
>
> Port: 3050
>
> Server: Firebird 1.5
>
> login: тра-та-та
>
> password: тра-та-та

```
    try {
        Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "тра-та-та");
        props.setProperty("password", "тра-та-та");

        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:firebirdsql:193.110.163.13:3050",
                    props);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Но я ловлю ошибку:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:firebirdsql:193.110.163.13/3050

Как правильно организовать роботу с этой базой данных? Нужно ли абсолютный путь к файлу database?

Comment: и драйвер при этом подключен в зависимостях?

Comment: Разобрался как правильно подключить драйвер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно включить в проект JDBC-драйвер Firebird для Android.

Насколько мне известно, единственная реализация — этот проект https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidjaybird/

Comment: Спасибо! У меня такая вот ошибка дальше: `org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544344. I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "3080"
Error while trying to open file
null` Я так понял мне нужно указывать абсолютный путь к файлу базы данных?

Comment: Путь или алиас. В любом случае придется править конфиги, т.к. по умолчанию FB запрещает удаленное подключение к себе. Для тренировок с настройкой я бы посоветовал поставить десктопный клиент Firebird, например, IBExpert, и потренироваться в нем.